# Google Domains only works with Google open DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, domains, opendns, google-domains

I purchased a domain with Google domains, but I can only use the DNS with computers that have Google Open DNS connected.  I connect the computer to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` for DNS, but on any other computer it says that it cannot find the server.  How would I make the domain name work on ANY network/computer?  Feel free to ask if you need more information.  Thank you!

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: www.eltrin.com is the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any A records for your root domain,  but it seems to resolve correctly.   I have Google domains and have had zero issues.

https://dnsquery.org/dnstraversal/eltrin.com/ANY

This link does not use cache.

Comment: The free dynamic dns is fantastic too

Comment: @CliftonM you might want to CNAME `www to @` also

Comment: I changed it all up, so www works correctly

Comment: I saw that. I'll look into it more.